# CSS Background-Image styling for HR disables other rules

Tags: css, firefox

I have run into what I think is a strange CSS bug:

When I use `background-image` to style `hr`, none of the rules or selectors placed after this rule will display on my page:

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

**Firefox** dev tools only show that I have 1 active rule, even though there are many rules after this in the sheet. I just moved this to the end, and everything worked fine.

**Is there are reason for this that I do not understand?** I feel like I am missing something simple that is causing this.

Comment: Usually this happens when the parser reaches a rule it can't parse; like a typo, for example. Check if you are closing braces and semi-colons;

Comment: There's a missing `)` in the penultimate `-ms-linear-gradient`, `background-image`, rule.

Comment: Grrrr, I looked and looked and looked. I feel like an idiot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

you have a missing: `)` at the end.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this :/

Comment: As a matter of fact, this line should be deleted altogether - `-ms-linear-gradient` is not used by any functional version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

you missed a closing parenthesis in the -ms-linear-gradient line.